# How to connect a GUI terminal emulator to a virtual console?

Tags: terminal, virtual-consoles

I use full-screen virtual consoles (those you can switch to with Ctrl+Alt+Fx) actively but some times I would like to view/interact with them via an X terminal window without actually switching to them. Is it possible to connect a GUI terminal emulator like Konsole or other to some of them, see/do something and disconnect while leaving the shell instance running there active and connect again some time after perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

you can then use tmux or screen on vTTYs (those you can switch to with Ctrl+Alt+Fx)

& then attach sessions into a Xterm or any other Graphical Terminal you want to use; of course you can also detach them after that etc...

If you really want to keep thoses sessions on vTTYs